# SQLite Asp.net Path

Tags: asp.net, sqlite

When using data source=|DataDirectory|\mydb.sqlite in Visual Studio 2008, I cannot see the tables in query builder or in the Dataset designer. How can I fix this? It is a web application for .NET 3.5.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have used `relative path` for local and `|DataDirectory|\mydb.sqlite` for web server. 
It works in this way